# Can I withdraw cash from margin?

Tags: cash, withdrawal, margin

Let's assume I have $100,000 worth in stocks: $50,000 I paid for in cash and the other $50,000 on margin. Can I sell the shares bought on margin and withdraw those $50,000 out of the brokerage account into a regular bank account? Common sense dictates that the broker would say no because doing so immediately increases the risk for them since the remaining $50,000 worth of securities could go down in value at any time. However, I've seen people saying online that they have done this without any problems to make house down payments and all sorts of things.

There are a couple of possible explanations:

1- The Reg T's minimum 25% maintenance margin rule does not only apply when securities go down in value, it also applies to withdrawals. In this case the broker would only allow to withdraw up to $37,500.

2- Brokers do not allow this at all and I completely misunderstood what other people are saying online.

So which is it?

Comment: I've had checking drawing on margin (though I haven't used it in a decade thus a comment if law has changed)  If the whole position will remain solvent, they honor the check then test for a margin call.

Answer (score 4):

I found your wording confusing, but I think it's your #1.  More specifically, if you have a margin account, you can usually withdraw cash in excess of your cash holdings *as long as your account will still be within the margin requirements after the withdrawl.*  As with any margin situation, if you push it to the limit and then the holdings that are the collateral decrease in value, you may get a margin call.